# php `use` class in parent folder

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, propel

I have installed [Propel ORM](http://propelorm.org/) with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) but I cannot create a new model as the PHP script is not in the same directory as the PHP class.

I have class `Test` inside `Test.php`  and I want to use it from `subfolder/index.php`. Note that class `Test` then uses `Base/Test` from `Base/Test.php`, so using `require()` is not an option here as `Base/Test` just goes on to use even more classes generated  by composer.

Traditionally, I'm supposed to do the following:

```
<?php
   use Test;
?>
```

but since I have `Test` in the parent folder, I cannot do that, and obviously

```
<?php
   use ../Test;
?>
```

doesn't work.

My folder structure:

```
My Project
|-- Base
|   `-- Test.php <-- File referenced by `Test` class
|-- subfolder
|   `-- index.php <-- File I want to use `Test` from
`-- Test.php <-- File containing `Test` class
```

**The Actual Code:**
`subfolder/index.php`:

```
<?php 
use \Test;
    require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
    $test = new Test();
?>
```

`Test.php`:

```
<?php
use Base\Test as BaseTest;

class Test extends BaseTest
{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Test` is a namespace and has literally nothing to do with folder structure. Namespaces have a folder-*like* structure, but you cannot use relative paths.

PSR-4 autoloaders, such as what most Composer packages use these days, map their namespaces in a way that *very closely matches* the folder structure, but they are still entirely separate concepts.

If you have declared a namespace in a file all subsequent names are considered to be relative to that path. eg:

```
namespace Foo;

class Bar {}; // \Foo\Bar
```

If you want to use something *outside* of the current namespace you need to declare the full path, beginning with `\` which signifies the *root* namespace. eg:

```
namespace Foo;
use \Test

class Bar { // \Foo\Bar
  public function test() {
    $test = new Test();
    $dbh = new \PDO();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to how the "root" namespace is defined. So for example, I put `namespace Foo;` in both `Test.php` and `index.php`, but `use \Test` from `index.php` still doesn't work. I have updated my question with the actual code of `Test.php` and `index.php` prior to the namespace modification

Comment: adding `Test.php` and `Base/` to the composer autoload classmaps made everything work - thank you for informing me that these aren't based off of folder structure!

Comment: @KevinPei Bah, I was just about finished typing that out in long-form. Glad you got it working.

Comment: You wouldn't normally start the `use` clause with a backslash because the argument always has to be a fully qualified namespace identifier - you cannot `use` something with a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Just set all the folder that you want in the composer.json file. Like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Config\\": "config/"
    },
    "files": [
        "config/config.php"
    ]
},
```

Search about the composer.json tho learn more about it. For the example above i chose the namespaces "App" and "Config" for the directories "app/" and "config/" in the root directory of my project AND chose the file "config/config.php" to be running BEFORE any action in my project.